# Unit-тест на ArgumentException или ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Надо написать Unit-тест на проверку поведения на null

```
public string Сity
{ 
    get => сity;
    set => сity = value ??
        throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(value), message: "City cannot  be null");
}
```

или на исключение с сообщением

```
public int Phone_number
{
    get => phone_number;
    set
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int resylt))
        {
            phone_number = resylt;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Phone number can contain only numbers");
        }
    }
}
```

Примерно такие тесты можно? Я не спец, только учусь) может подскажете более интересное решение.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void CheekName_name_nameRetyrned()
{
    // Arrange
    string x = "name";
    string expected = "name";

    // Action
    Person p = new Person();
    p.Name = x;
    string actual = p.Name;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Надо написать Unit-тест, который завершался положительно в случае, когда оба этих параметра получали не корректные данные. К примеру свойство Name поручало Null, из-за чего оно выкидывало ArgumentNullException. Вопрос в том - как правильное его написать?

Comment: о каком юнит-тесте речь? Есть разные библиотеке типа NUnit, или микрософтовской, или можно просто руками сделать метод в котором отловить исключение и вывести в консоль например

Comment: Добавь всю необходимую информацию непосредственно в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: Не понятен код в сеттере свойства `Phone_number`. Оно имеет тип `int`, поэтому ничего, кроме целых чисел ему невозможно присвоить. И смысл этого `TryParse` от меня ускользает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки ожидаемых исключений есть атрибут [`[ExpectedException]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0).

Его можно использовать примерно так:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))
public void CheekName_name_nameRetyrned()
{
    Person p = new Person();
    p.City = null;
}
```

Однако в данном случае не проверяется само сообщение, только тип.

Аналогично можно использовать метод [`Assert.ThrowsException<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.throwsexception?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_Assert_ThrowsException__1_System_Action_)

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheekName_name_nameRetyrned()
{
    Person p = new Person();

    Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentNullException>(() => p.City = null);
}
```

---

Атрибутов для проверки сообщения исключения нет, однако, можно написать такой атрибут самому, унаследовавшись от [`ExpectedExceptionBaseAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionbaseattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) и переопределив метод [`Verify`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionbaseattribute.verify?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_ExpectedExceptionBaseAttribute_Verify_System_Exception_)

Например так:

```
class ExpectedExceptionWithMessage : ExpectedExceptionBaseAttribute
{
    private Type expectedExceptionType;
    private string expectedMessage;
    public ExpectedExceptionWithMessage(Type expectedExceptionType, string expectedMessage)
    {
        this.expectedExceptionType = expectedExceptionType;
        this.expectedMessage = expectedMessage;
    }

    protected override void Verify(Exception exception)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedExceptionType, exception.GetType());
        // при использовании конструктора исключения с именем параметра
        // к сообщению добавляется строка с указанием имени параметра
        // чтобы она на влияла на проверку проверяем только первую строку сообщения
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedMessage, exception.Message?.Split(Environment.NewLine)?[0]);
    }
}
```

Использовать можно так:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedExceptionWithMessage(typeof(ArgumentNullException), "City cannot  be null")
public void CheekName_name_nameRetyrned()
{
    Person p = new Person();
    p.City = null;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можете написать пример и отловом самого сообщения?

Comment: @Heksys, обновил ответ